# How do I write a query in SQL Server that utilizes Regex

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2012

I want to return all rows where columnX has 10 digits of numerics and nothing else (e.g. '1234567890').  The column in question has other formatted data such as 4 alphas and 4 numerics (e.g. ABCD1234), etc.

I want to utilize my regex in SQL Server 2012 queries.

Answer (score 1):

There is no regexp in sql server.

You can use `try_cast` which returns `null` when there are any alphabets in the column when you `cast` it to an `bigint`.

```
select * from tablename
where try_cast(columnX as bigint) is not null
```

Edit: To check if the column length = 10 add one more condition to the `where` clause.

```
select * from tablename
where try_cast(columnX as bigint) is not null and len(columnX) = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server REGEX uses the `LIKE` clause with `%` but for your case you can do this:

```
SELECT columX
FROM TableT
WHERE ISNUMERIC(columnX) = 1 and LEN(C1) = 10
```

Comment: thanks - another great workaround.  Can you expand on what you mean by using the Like clause for regex?  I know the basic use of the like clause, but are you saying there is a way to write more advanced Regex into a like clause?

Comment: @ColinMac sorry, i see how what i said could be confusing. `LIKE` is the closest thing you'll get to `REGEX` without a lengthy CASE statement or something similar. `LIKE` can use some `REGEX` type characters such as `_ % [] and ^` but you can't use it like you can other languages such as Java. So generally speaking you can so "No Regex in SQL Server" as you did.

Comment: *can say "No Regex in SQL Server"